# Error in ng-options using ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-options

i'm developig an hybrid app using Ionic and i've a problem with a view, in my project i've a js file for every controller and in the index.html i "include" them with a script src...

All the controllers works fine, but in a view i've a problem to populate two selects in a form, them were always empty but if i use it like a simple html file (so with the classic structure, head, body, etc.) and i include here the file with the controller (but declaring an angular module) and insert the ng-app and the ng-controller in the body it works properly.

This is my code:

**HTML**:

```
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <div>
            <div>
                <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()">
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Giorno:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Ora:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules| filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item item-toggle">
                    &Egrave un'urgenza?
                    <label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div align="center">
                <input class="button button-calm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Prenota !">            
            </div>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
ionicApp.controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);

DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService', '$http'];

function DefaultController(dataService, $http) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log("Dentro ctrl");
  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
      console.log("Dentro getEvents");
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
          console.log("data: " + data);
        vm.data = data;
        console.log("vm.data: " + vm.data);
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
    vm.submit = function (){
        console.log("funzione");
        console.log(vm.form);
        var data = vm.form; // IMPORTANT
        //console.clear();
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api/apiDoFix.php';
        var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
        var scelta = window.localStorage.getItem("scelta");
        console.log(data);
        console.log ("EMAIL" + mail);
        console.log ("SCELTA" + scelta);
        $http.post(link, {giorno: data.giorno, ora: data.ora, mail: mail, scelta: scelta})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                var response = res.data;
                if (response != 'F'){
                    console.log("Dentro if");
                    console.log(response);
                    //window.location.href ="/#/main";
                } else {
                    console.log("Dentro else");
                }
            });
    };
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
    console.log("qua");
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
      console.log("qua2");
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          schedules: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        console.log("qua3");
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }

          result.schedules.push({
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
          });
        }
        console.log("result: " + result);
        return result;
      }
    };

    return $http.get('http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api/apiTimes.php', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);
    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
        console.log("response " + response.data);
      return response.data;
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

With this code the controller was execute bu the two selects are empty.

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: Which ionic/angular version are you using?

Comment: i'm using ionic 1 and angular 1 @PaulWasilewski